# Shell command to access db in Flask

Tags: python, database, flask

I'd like to access the database configured in the setting via a shell command in Flask. Is there any equivalent command in Flask to `python manage.py dbshell` in Django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no such command exists for flask , but you can access your db with normal db clients